# Are Unity's "MonoBehaviour Components" equivalent to systems from the Entity-Component-System design pattern?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, components, entity, composition

I am working on making a very simple 2D game engine, and I am in the process of redoing my entities to work somewhat like Unity's system. I have been doing research on how the Entity-Component-System design pattern (ECS) works, and I am beginning to understand it better.

As I understand, a **component** in ECS only holds data and is not capable of doing anything but retain that data. These components are then used by **systems** which are used to read and manipulate their data.

This led me to question is if the MonoBehaviour scripts that are attached to a GameObject in Unity are technically systems and not components as they are called in the Unity editor?

If I am mistaken, I think it would be helpful for me to analyze true implementations of ECS. I am coding in Java, so if anyone has any examples of an ECS system implemented in Java or C#, that would be great as most of the examples I have seen were in C++ which is a bit more difficult for me to understand.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity doesn't strictly work via an ECS, despite using the term "Component." A Unity component, in the form of a `MonoBehaviour`, can have both data and system logic. [Unity will, in future versions, be rolling out an ECS model](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS).

If you'd like to use current Unity versions (2018.1 and below) and strictly adhere to an ECS methodology, I'd suggest looking into [Entitas and their Unity Plugin](https://github.com/sschmid/Entitas-CSharp). You can also choose to structure your code, assets, and scenes to conform to ECS principles but Entitas is very efficient and solves a lot of problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

the mono system in unity can be called EC(entity-component) which is base on Object-oriented design.
the ECS(entity-component-system) is base on Data-oriented design.
there is both data and logic in a mono component.